# javax.validation.constraints @Email not return custom message and regex?

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, validation, spring-boot

I am new in validation.

controller:

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class AccountController
{
    @PostMapping( value = "/account/location" )
    public ResponseEntity<LocationAccountVO> createLocationAccount( @RequestHeader 
HttpHeaders headers,@Valid @RequestBody LocationAccountVO locationAccountVO ) throws 
NumberParseException
    {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body( 
accountService.createLocationAccount( locationAccountVO ) );
    }
}
```

LoacationVo.java:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL )
public class LocationAccountVO
{
private UUID locationId;
    @NotNull(message = "Email is mandatory.")
    @Email( regexp = ValidationConstant.EMAIL, message = "Email be valid")
    private String email;
}
```

`public static final String EMAIL = "\\\\b[A-Z]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\\\b";`

but `@Email` not giving custom message and pattern also not working.Kindly solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace 4 backslash sequences with ``\\``. Actually, the `\\b` at both ends are redundant, remove them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  `\b[A-Z]+@[A-Z0-9]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`  is this correct?

Comment: I don't know Hibernate validation but unless it is case-insensitive all emails would have to use upper case only and your regex also would not allow for emails like `name.familyname@domain.co.uk`

Comment: @Thomas is this correct `^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@`?

Comment: You do not need anchors if the pattern is used with `matches`, `public static final String EMAIL = "[A-Z]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}";` should be enough. But it is too restrictive. Consider something like `"\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This means that if i enter `ankit@gmail.com`, then it is wrong?

Comment: `"[A-Z]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}"` won't match it.  That is why I suggest just a very generic `"\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still problem not solved. I think the issue is with `javax.validation.constraints.Email`

Comment: Have you used it before?

Comment: " not giving custom message and pattern also not working" and "still problem not solved" - _you_ might want to consider telling us what exactly isn't working/in what way it isn't working. What do you feed to the validator, what do you expect to get and what do you get instead?

Comment: when i put regex and try to send invalid email id(not match patter), error message i got is default of `@Email`.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement like that.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL )
public class LocationAccountVO
{
private UUID locationId;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is mandatory.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", message = "Email be valid")
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: I have used that and it's working check the following link
https://github.com/faizakram/Application

Answer (score 0):

1- Add the necessary dependencies in pom.xml file from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C(g%3A%22org.springframework.boot%22%20AND%20(a%3A%22spring-boot-starter-validation%22%20OR%20a%3A%22spring-boot-starter-web%22))):

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-validation

2- Add the necessary Annotations in your form bean:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}")
@Email
private String email;
```

3- To read messages from message.properties, you have to define the MessageSource Bean

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

4- To avoid having the custom validator ignored, you have to set the validator by overriding the getValidator() method. Set validation message source to message.properties.

```
@Bean(name = "validator")
@Override
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

5- in the message.properties file under src/main/resources
just define a property message like:

```
email.notempty=This field is required.
```

note : If it does not work yet you can still do this.

```
javax.validation.constraints.Email.message=Please provide valid email id.
```